# Why is Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] missing when using Chrome or IE9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code:

```
var httpCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];
```

This works in Firefox. [".ASPXAUTH"] is listed and found. However in Chrome and IE9 it is missing and thus httpCookie is null.

Why is this and how can I resolve this please?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the cookie of the authentication of your application, you could try something like this:

```
HttpCookie appCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

to Decrypt it, you could use:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(appCookie.Value);

// you can access all properties using the 'ticket' object. 
string cookikePath = ticket.CookiePath;
DateTime expiration = ticket.Expiration;
bool expired = ticket.Expired;
bool isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
DateTime issueDate = ticket.IssueDate;
string name = ticket.Name;
string userData = ticket.UserData;
string version = ticket.Version;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this I have posted the full code. I am using it to download a Word document to the browser.

Comment: Try to adapt your code to get the cookie using `context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];`.

Comment: Felipe, I have sorted it. Bit of a basic mistake. I had not logged into my application when using Chrome or IE. I usually use FF, so the cookie was there. Thanks, really appreciate your help. I have ticked your answer since I am sure this will be of assistance to others.

Comment: Maybe in the future it can help someone :)